# Is such a field element an element of a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

This is a variation of Problem 8.21 on p.119 of *The Theory of Algebraic Numbers* by Harry Pollard and Harold G. Diamond (Dover edition).

> Let $K$ be a field, $R$ a subring of $K$ (with $1\in R$), and $I\ne\{0\}$ an ideal of $R$. Suppose $\beta\in K$ is such that for all $\alpha\in I$, we have $\beta\alpha\in I$. Is it true that $\beta\in R$?

In the original problem, $K$ is an algebraic-number field and $R$ the subring of algebraic integers; in that case $\beta\in R$ is true (though I can't prove it yet as I haven't finished reading the chapter on which this set of problems is based). I am just wondering if the problem can be meaningfully restated in the general context of fields and rings. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: $R=\mathbb Z+X\mathbb Q[X]$, and $I=X\mathbb Q[X]$. Then $\frac12 I\subseteq I$, but $\frac 12\notin R$.

Comment: @user26857 $R$ has to be a subring of a field. What is a field $K$ of which $R$ is a subring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if this counterexample is too complicated, but I couldn't find a simpler one.

Let $K= \Bbb{Q}(X,Y)$,  and $$R= \left\{ a+Y\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} : a \in \Bbb{Q}, f,g \in \Bbb{Q}[X,Y]  , g(X,0) \neq 0 \right\} $$
You can check that $R$ is a (unital) subring of $K$ and that $X \notin R$. Call $$I=\left\{ a+Y\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} \in R: a = 0 \right\},$$ and $\beta=X$. Recall, $\beta \notin R$.

$I$ is an ideal of $R$, because it is the kernel of the ring morphism $$\begin{matrix} R &\longrightarrow & \Bbb{Q} \\ a + Y\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} & \longmapsto & a  \end{matrix}$$

Finally, for all $\alpha = 0+ Y\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} \in I$ we have
$$\beta \alpha = X \left( 0+ Y\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} \right) = 0+Y \frac{Xf(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} \in I$$

Comment: In fact, you consider $R=\mathbb Q+Y\mathbb Q[X,Y]_{(Y)}$, and $I=Y\mathbb Q[X,Y]_{(Y)}$. A little more complicated than my example, but in the same "spirit".

Comment: Yes, I simply wrote everything explicitly in order that the OP can understand without knowing what a localization is.